Are any two recursive languages reducible to one another?
Given two recursive languages A and B with alphabets $\Sigma$ and $\Delta$ respectively, is there always a computable function $f:\Sigma^*\rightarrow\Delta^*$ such that $x\in A \iff f(x)\in B$?
(other than the case where $B = \emptyset$)

This is almost true, with the only exception being trivial languages: ($\Sigma^*$ and $\emptyset$).
Note that the claim can be made stronger: you don't even need $B$ to be decidable (i.e., recursive).
By definition, there is no reduction from $\Sigma^*$ to $\emptyset$ nor from $\emptyset$ to $\Delta^*$.
However, for all other pairs, the claim is true. Indeed, assume that both $B\neq \emptyset$ and $B\neq \Delta^*$. This means there are two words $x\in B$ and $y\notin B$.
We also assume that $A$ is recursive, so there is a Turing Machine $M$ that decides $A$.
We can now define the following computable reduction: given input $w$, run $M$ on $w$. If $M$ accepts, output $x$. If $M$ rejects, output $y$.
$M$ always halts, so this is well defined and computable, and since $M$ decides $A$, this is trivially correct.
The underlying idea behind this solution is that if the computational power of your reductions is greater (or equal) to the class you're reducing from, then the reduction itself can solve the input problem. Therefore, you can reduce to any (nontrivial) language.
The same phenomenon occurs when using e.g., polynomial-time reductions from P, or PSPACE reductions from PSPACE.

I believe that there's a minor mistake in the argumentation about the cases involving Σ* / Δ* / ∅ - the condition is stronger: For B=∅, this reduction is possible iff A=∅, and for B=Δ*, it's possible iff A=Σ*. Apart from that, there are no restrictions on A: for example, a reduction of ∅ to any language B other than Δ* is possible. The reason is that if B=∅, there is by definition no x∈B - but as long as A is nonempty, f has to output some x∈B for at least one input, namely those ∈A. Conversely for B=Δ*: then, there's no y∉B, but if A≠Σ*, f has to output some y∉B for at least one input.

@Haspamelodica -- what you wrote is correct and consistent with my answer, I just avoided talking about these two cases because they're not at the heart of matters.
